# Why my VAE for toy dateset doesn't learn?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I played with VAE (Variational Auto-encoder) for a couple of days. It works pretty well on the demo dataset like mnist or frayface. However, when I apply it to my own dataset, it doesn't work at all.

I cannot find any reference regarding the potential difficulties in training VAE, so I made a tiny test case.

My toy dataset is as follows:

```
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.choice([0.05, 0.95], n)
```

And my VAE structure is like:

```
X -> hidden layer 1 (50 units)
  -> hidden layer 2 (50 units)
  -> code layer (1 units)
  -> sampling layer (1 sampling)
  -> hidden layer 3 (50 units)
  -> hidden layer 4 (50 units)
  -> X (with Bernoulli loss + KL)
```

The input is a probability, I hope after learning, VAE can figure out that the latent variable is actually X itself.

However, I tried Bernoulli as well as Gaussian loss for the output layer, neither works.

The code layer is stuck with the prior N(0,1), hence the prediction is always around 0.5.

The toy script is here, https://gist.github.com/colinfang/20abd925ad3140236e63. The majority of the code comes from https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-11-27/vae.html

Answer (score 0):

One very common problem that occur in VAEs is 'Posterior Collapse' (see here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48962/what-is-posterior-collapse-phenomenon).

If this is indeed the case, I suggest looking at the solution here:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-a-Variational-Autoencoder-VAE-that-suffers-from-mode-collapse

It worked out well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a VAE that works on moderately sized datasets (no mode collapse etc) and updating/adapting for the kind of dataset you're passionate about. I've applied a [VAE for new fruits](https://becominghuman.ai/variational-autoencoders-for-new-fruits-with-keras-and-pytorch-6d0cfc4eeabd) to a 1000 element dataset of furniture (recliners) I collected, with a modicum of success (shapes and some texture emulated, but not yet a truly notable imitation).